# I need a regex that finds substrings in a CQL string split by occurrences of AND and OR outside quotes and taking escaped quotes into account

Tags: java, regex, cql

In this example source string:

```
index1 = "searchterm1" AND (index2 any "\"value2.1\" \"value2.2 AND sometext\" \"value2.3 OR sometext\"") OR index3 = "searchterm3"
```

The source needs to be splitted by the following bold text:

`index1 = "searchterm1"` **AND** `(index2 any "\"value2.1\" \"value2.2 AND sometext\" \"value2.3` **OR** `sometext\"") OR index3 = "searchterm3"`

I expect this to be the result:

**match 1** with group 1: `index1 = "searchterm1"`

**match 2** with group 1: `AND` and group 2:`(index2 any "\"value2.1\" \"value2.2 AND sometext\" \"value2.3`

**match 3** with group 1: `OR` and group 2: `sometext\"") OR index3 = "searchterm3"`

**I tried this:**

`\b(AND|OR)(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`

but those escaped quotes are giving me a hard time.

**EDIT:**

An other example:

```
index1 = "searchterm1" AND (index2 any "\"value2.1\" \"value2.2 AND sometext\" \"value2.3 OR sometext\"")) OR (index3 = "searchterm3" AND (index4 any "\"value4.1\" \"value4.2 OR sometext\" \"value4.3 AND sometext\"") AND index5 = "searchterm5"
```

where it should be splitted by the following bold text:

`index1 = "searchterm1"` **AND** `(index2 any "\"value2.1\" \"value2.2 AND sometext\" \"value2.3 OR sometext\""))` **OR** `(index3 = "searchterm3"` **AND** `(index4 any "\"value4.1\" \"value4.2 OR sometext\" \"value4.3 AND sometext\"")` **AND** `index5 = "searchterm5"`

Comment: Check your post. Are double stars `**` part of your data or was the bold text intentional?

Comment: @lemon: Double stars are not part of the source-string. Just to make clear on which to split

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you share the source text from which to extract these matches?

Comment: @lemon: source text as is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(AND|OR|^).*?(?:\1.*?)*(?=(AND|OR|$))
```

It will match:

- `(AND|OR|^)`: AND, OR or the start of string symbol
- `.*?`: the least amount of characters that are followed by
- `(?:\1.*?)*`: the same AND, OR sequence of characters and the any other characters - optionally
- `(?=(AND|OR|$))`: AND, OR or the end of string symbol

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yJCepQ/1).

Comment: I have just edit the question because your solution was not for all situations correct. Can you have an other look. I think the problem lies in the escaped quotes

Comment: Your current source data has a different nature of the previous source data: they are generated by different grammars, the latter by a Type-3, the former by a Type-2 Grammar, which can't be handled by regex. You should be looking for some parsing operation in java more than regex solutions, and it becomes a completely different problem.